# Generate html tags with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, angular, ngfor

Is it possible to use AngularJS 2.0 to generate html tags. I am using Polymer, and am trying to populate a dashboard with the widgets defined in a `User`s `entitlements`.

I believe you have to have the `<li></li>` tags for NgFor? So could you do something like:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#entitlement of entitlements; #i = index">
        <{{ entitlement }}></{{ entitlement }}>
    </li>
</ul>
```

to generate something like:

```
<li>
    <google-map></google-map> //would probably also need a `params` element in the first tag, i.e. latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942"
</li>
<li>
    <google-youtube></google-youtube>
</li>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's correct way to program in ng2. But you might want to see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#entitlement of entitlements; #i = index"
        [innerHTML]="entitlement">
    </li>
</ul>
```

where `entitlement` is `<google-map></google-map>`.

You can't create Angular components this way, but should work fine with Polymer elements.